# Seeking Formalization or Verification of an Inequality Involving Sums and Products

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs, combinatorics-on-words, rough-path-theory

**Body:**

Hello everyone,

I've been working on an inequality involving sums and products over certain functions and indices, and I've come up with a proof sketch. However, I'm not entirely sure about its correctness and would appreciate any insights on how to formalize it better or even just to verify if the inequality holds.

**Inequality Statement**

Consider the following inequality:

**Left-Hand Side (LHS):**
$$
\sum_{P_1 * P_2 * \ldots * P_n = R} \left( \omega(t_1)^{\frac{n_1(P_1)}{p_1}} \cdots \omega(t_n)^{\frac{n_1(P_n)}{p_1}} \right) \cdots \left( \omega(t_1)^{\frac{n_k(P_1)}{p_k}} \cdots \omega(t_n)^{\frac{n_k(P_n)}{p_k}} \right)
$$

**Right-Hand Side (RHS) in Ellipsis Notation:**
$$
\left( \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_n \in \mathbb{N} : i_1 + \cdots + i_n = n_1(R)} \omega(t_1)^{\frac{i_1}{p_1}} \cdots \omega(t_n)^{\frac{i_n}{p_1}} \right) \cdots \left( \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_n \in \mathbb{N} : i_1 + \cdots + i_n = n_k(R)} \omega(t_1)^{\frac{i_1}{p_k}} \cdots \omega(t_n)^{\frac{i_n}{p_k}} \right)
$$

**Proof Sketch**

Consider a specific term in the LHS summation defined by a fixed sequence of words $P_1, P_2, ..., P_n$ that concatenate to form $R$. For simplicity, let's focus on the number 1 and its corresponding counts in the words $P_i$.

The contribution of each word $P_i$ to the count of the number 1 in $R$ is given by $n_1(P_i)$. The sum of these counts, $n_1(P_1) + \cdots + n_1(P_n)$, equals $n_1(R)$, as it enumerates the occurrences of 1 in $R$.

In the RHS, the first term (for $\ell = 1$) sums over all tuples $(i_1, ..., i_n)$ in the naturals that add up to $n_1(R)$. The LHS term for $P_1, P_2, ..., P_n$ corresponds to one such tuple in this RHS summation.

Extending this reasoning to all $k$ terms in the RHS, we see that each term in the LHS can be matched to a specific product of terms in the RHS summations. Consequently, the LHS is bounded above by the RHS, as it is a sum of such terms.

**Definitions**

- $\omega(t_i)$: Positive numbers representing specific functions of $t_i$.
- $n_\ell(P_i)$: A function counting the occurrences of the number $\ell$ in the word $P_i$.
- $R = (r_1, r_2, ..., r_m)$: A tuple consisting of $m$ elements, each being a number ranging from 1 to $k$.
- Words $P_1, P_2, ..., P_n$: Words that concatenate to form $R$, including the possibility of empty words.

**Question**

Is there a way to formalize this proof sketch better? Additionally, I'm not completely certain if this inequality is true, but I have a strong suspicion that it is. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!